# Why is the letter f used at the end of a float no.?

Tags: java

I just wanted some information about this.

```
float n = 2.99944323200023f
```

What does the `f` at the end of the literal do? What is it called? Why is it used?

Comment: The "F" indicates that the literal numeric value it is appended to is a float value. This is necessary information for the compiler and if not present can lead to errors or the compiler otherwise interpreting the number incorrectly.

Comment: @ScoPi I tried it out in a program and it rounds it off to 5 decimal places.As I have understood, a float no. has a range of 10^-38 to 10^38.

Comment: @crvineeth99 only a small amount of distinct values in that range can be represented in a float. Theoretically there is space for ~4.3 billion different values in a float, yet the range `10^-38 to 10^38` has infinity amount of different values.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `f` indicates it's a floating point literal, not a double literal (which it would implicitly be otherwise.) It hasn't got a particular technical name that I know of - I tend to call it the "letter suffix" if I need to refer to it specifically, though that's somewhat arbitrary!

For instance:

```
float f = 3.14f; //Compiles
float f = 3.14;   //Doesn't compile, because you're trying to put a double literal in a float without a cast.
```

You could of course do:

```
float f = (float)3.14;
```

...which accomplishes near enough the same thing, but the F is a neater, more concise way of showing it.

Why was double chosen as the default rather than float? Well, these days the memory requirements of a double over a float aren't an issue in 99% of cases, and the extra accuracy they provide is beneficial in a lot of cases - so you could argue that's the sensible default.

Note that you can explicitly show a decimal literal as a double by putting a `d` at the end also:

```
double d = 3.14d;
```

...but because it's a double value anyway, this has no effect. Some people might argue for it advocating it's clearer what literal type you mean, but personally I think it just clutters code (unless perhaps you have a lot of float literals hanging around and you want to emphasise that this literal is indeed meant to be a double, and the omission of the f isn't just a bug.)

Comment: "which accomplishes near enough the same thing" I'm particularly interested if the "near". Isn't it exactly the same thing?

Comment: @leonbloy Well, in practice it is exactly the same thing - there's a somewhat theoretical difference that by doing the cast without the f you're essentially providing a double literal and then chopping the accuracy to a float value, rather than just providing a float literal to start with. But yes, functionality wise it's identical.

Comment: Any performance implications this would have - or should the compiler already deal with these things?

Comment: @Chris Nope (I haven't checked the bytecode to see if things are exactly the same, but certainly none that are worth worrying about.)

Answer (score 6):

The default Java type which Java will be using for a float variable will be double. So, even if you declare any variable as float, what compiler has to actually do is to assign a double value to a float variable, which is not possible.So, to tell compiler to treat this value as a float, that 'f' is used.

Comment: "So, even if you declare any variable as float, memory allocated to it will be same as that of a double, instead of a float." What?! If you declare a float, you can't put a double into it without casting - and therefore bringing the value down to 32 bits rather than 64.

Comment: But, if you directly try to assign such a value to a float variable without using 'f', it gives a compiler error 'Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to float', which means it's treating it like a double, which will surely consume 64 bits.

Comment: The compiler error is generated due to just that - a type mismatch, not a memory mismatch.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, when you type a decimal number as `3.6`, its interpreted as a `double`. `double` is a 64-bit precision IEEE 754 floating point, while `float`is a 32-bit  precision IEEE 754 floating point. As a `float` is less precise than a `double`, the conversion cannot be performed implicitly.

If you want to create a float, you should end your number with `f` (i.e.: `3.6f`).

For more explanation, see the [primitive data types definition of the Java tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's to distinguish between floating point and double precision numbers.  The latter has no suffix.

Comment: Yes, they have: `double` litterals suffixes are `d` and `D`. But you can omit them.

Answer (score 1):

When you write 1.0, it's ambiguous as to whether you intend the literal to be a float or double. By writing 1.0f, you're telling Java that you intend the literal to be a float, while using 1.0d specifies that it should be a double (which is also default if you do not specify that explicitely).

Comment: Not my downvote, but the statement "it's ambiguous as to whether you intend the literal to be a float or double" is wrong - in the JLS it states it's a double by default, so there's never any ambiguity there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the 'f' at the end, otherwise Java will assume its a double.

Answer (score 1):

It means that it's a [single precision floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision) literal rather than [double precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision). Otherwise, you'd have to write `float n = (float)2.99944323200023;` to cast the double to single.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Oracle Java Tutorial, section Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) under *Floating-Point Literals*

> A floating-point literal is of type float if it ends with the letter F or f; otherwise its type is double and it can optionally end with the letter D or d.

Answer (score 1):

If `f` is not precised at the end, value is considered to be a `double`. 
And a `double` leads to more bytes in memory than `float`.

Answer (score 0):

For the new versions of C lang, the conversion from double input to a float variable (assigning operation) is done by the compiler without the 'F'

```
float fraction1 = 1337;
float fraction2 = 1337.0;
float fraction3 = 1337.0F;
printf("%f, %f, %f", fraction1, fraction2, fraction3);

output(C GNU): 1337.000000, 1337.000000, 1337.000000
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).