# Java - Why floats require cast or 'f' suffix whereas long does not?

Tags: java

Why do I need to cast a float or put an 'f' suffix whereas long doesn't?

Why is the default data type for floating point numbers is double and not float?

For eg:

```
float foo = 0.5; //compilation error
float foo = 0.5f; //works
float foo = (float)0.5; //works
```

whereas

```
long bar = 10; //works
```

Why is Java designed in such a way?

Comment: Because `0.5` is a double.

Comment: Because an int is narrower than a long, whereas a double is wider than a float.

Comment: Because widening conversions don't require casts. A more relevant comparison would be between `float` and `short`.

Comment: @tkausl And 10 is an int. So that doesn't answer the question quite yet.

Comment: Here is the proper explanation given for your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704028/why-is-the-letter-f-used-at-the-end-of-a-float-no

Comment: Choice of the default types for **numeric literals**: for integral types is `int` (narrower, thus it can be converted to `long`) for floating point is `double` (larger, if you need a narrower one, you need to signal it somehow: either cast of suffix).

Answer (score 2):

The first one doesn't work because a double (`0.5` is a double literal) is *wider* than a float: it has more bits of data, so the assignment needs to throw away some of that data. You can explicitly cast it, but you have to make it clear that you intend to lose that extra data via the `(float)` cast.

The last one works because `10` is an int literal, and int is *narrower* than long: it has fewer bits of data, so you can assign an int to a long without losing data.

Comment: I need to know why 0.5 is a double literal by default and why java cannot cast 0.5 to a float implicitly?

Comment: @arnabkaycee If the answers and comments you've already been given don't satisfy you, the only remaining answer is 'because that's the way they designed it'.

Comment: That's just the way the language is specified. The only people who can answer "why" are Gosling et al.

Comment: @AndyTurner If I cast the value 0.5 as a float, what data do I lose by not casting as a double? Do you just mean the extra decimal places are lost? (Which for a value like 0.5, makes no practical difference?)